# Python how to improve this example?

Tags: python

I have a file:

```
one two three
four five six
```

I tried this command:

```
python -c "import sys; print ''.join(x.replace("two", "xxx") for x in sys.stdin)"  < file

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <genexpr>
NameError: global name 'two' is not defined
```

I want to get the result:

```
one xxx three
four five six
```

How to improve the above example?

Comment: Just change `x.replace("two", "xxx")` to `x.replace('two', 'xxx')` (with single quotes). You're having a shell problem, not a Python problem.

Comment: @lanzz: that's more an answer than a comment, no?

Comment: Yes, but the question is too trivial and probably not very on-topic as well.

Comment: First try to use x.replace('two', 'xxx') to don't have errors, because you use yet ", after what do you mean? ... is written inside the file there one two three
four five six ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to backshlash(escape)  the `two`  and `xxx`or single-quote it. 
This will work

`python -c "import sys; print ''.join(x.replace(\"two\", \"xxx\") for x in sys.stdin)"  < file`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't properly escape the double quotes

```
python -c 'import sys; print "".join(x.replace("two", "xxx") for x in sys.stdin)'  < filename
```

Comment: won't get 'SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal'?

Comment: @zhangxaochen: I tested it out on my machine before posting, and I didn't get a SyntaxError. Did you encounter such an error?

Comment: I get that error when using single quotes, e.g. `python -c 'import os'`, I'm on win7, py2(and py3)

Comment: @zhangxaochen: I'm on a *NIX system, and that's perhaps why we see contradictory behaviour.